# Get the index of item in list based on value

Tags: c#, linq, indexof

The scenario is for a football league table. I can order the list by match win percentage and then by goals scored to determine their position in the league. I then use this ordering to get teams position in the league table using the `IndexOf` function.

```
this.results = this.results.OrderByDescending(x => x.WinPercentage).ThenByDescending(x => x.Goals);


this.results.Foreach(x => x.Position = this.results.IndexOf(x));
```

The problem arises when two teams (should be joint #1) have the same match win percentage and goals scored but when getting the index one team will be assigned #1 and the other #2.

Is there a way to get the correct position?

Comment: I guess your problem has NO solution, once if two items (ANY) has the same score in a LIST, you will always have one behind the other. You must develop a way to assume same list position for two identical scores: I suggest you create a bidimensional array or LIST, where one of the values is the numerical position, and abandon the LIST position as the index of each team in league.

Comment: Yes, thats why I posted this question as my current method doesnt not work. I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction with other potential solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var position = 1;
 var last = result.First();
 foreach(var team in results)
 {
     if (team.WinPercentage != last.WinPercentage || team.Goals != last.Goals)
        ++position;

     team.Position = position;
     last = team;
 }
```

Comment: I take it that the position needs to be assigned to the team inside the if statement?

Comment: You'ere right.  The position assignment needs to go *after* the `if()`.  I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is group the items based on the win percentage and goals (if both are the same, the teams will be in the same group), then apply the same position number to every element in the same group:

```
this.results = this.results.OrderByDescending(x => x.WinPercentage).ThenByDescending(x => x.Goals);

var positionGroups = this.results.GroupBy(x => new { WinPercentage = x.WinPercentage, Goals = x.Goals });
int position = 1;
foreach (var positionGroup in positionGroups)
{
    foreach (var team in positionGroup)
    {
        team.Position = position;
    }
    position++;
}
```

Comment: This is the way I was thinking of doing it (with the group by) but im wondering is James Currans answer below more efficient as it only contains one foreach statement

Comment: @BadDub His answer is most definitely more efficient if that's what you're looking for. I just wanted to provide another alternative. Even though `GroupBy` is not the best solution for this problem, you'll now probably remember that it exists and have it in your repertoire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

The code below code will work for you

```
this.results = this.results.OrderByDescending(x => x.WinPercentage).ThenByDescending(x => x.Goals);


this.results.Foreach(x =>
{
    int index = this.results.FindIndex(y => y.Goals == x.Goals && y.WinPercentage == x.WinPercentage);
    x.Position = index > 0 ? this.results[index - 1].Position + 1 : 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

1. Define a class：

```
public class ABC
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int R { get; set; }
}
```

2. Constructing numerical：

```
List<ABC> list = new List<ABC>();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    list.Add(new ABC()
    {
        A = i,
        B = i > 50 && i < 70 ? i + 20 : i + 1
    });
}
```

3. Ranking and print the values:

```
var result = list.OrderByDescending(d => d.B)
            .GroupBy(d => d.B)
            .SelectMany((g, `i`) => g.Select(e => new ABC()
            {
                A = e.A,
                B = e.B,
                R = i + 1
            })).ToList();

foreach (var t in result)
{
   Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t));
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

4. the result：

[image]