# Linq List Ranking in C#

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I have the below list which consist of a list of names and scores. The scores I got from using linq to get the sum of points for the list of peope:

```
  Name  Score
   Ed    5
   John  6
   Sara  7
   Dean  3
   Nora  4
```

So i was able to group the list and make the sums, but now I am trying to rank these based on the score. So I am trying to get the below list:

```
Rank Name Score
 1   Sara  7
 2   John  6
 3   Ed    5
 4   Nora  4
 5   Dean  3
```

But the linq code I am using doesn't seem to be getting the right ranks for me.

Here's my code for making the list and making the sums and ranking:

```
    public class Person
    {

        public int Rank { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }

        public Person(int rank, string name, int score)
        {
            Rank = rank;
            Name = name;
            Score = score;

        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {            
 Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        var data = lines.Select(line => {
        var column = line.Split(',');
        var name = column[0];
        int score = int.Parse(column[1]);
        int rank =0; 
        return new { name, score, rank };
    });

        var groupedData = data.OrderByDescending(x => x.score).GroupBy(p => p.name).Select((g, i) => new { name = g.Key, rank=i+1, score = g.Sum(p => p.score)});

    var persons = groupedData.Select(p => new Person(p.rank, p.name, p.score));

    foreach (var person in persons) {
        Persons.Add(person);
    }
    datagrid.ItemsSource = Persons;
}
```

I just would like to know how to include correct ranks in linq.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to `OrderByDescending` the `groupedData` (which has a total score) rather than the raw data containing non-summed, individual scores.

```
var persons = groupedData.Select(p => new Person(p.rank, p.name, p.score)).OrderByDescending(x => x.Score);
```

*Edit*: (putting the correct rank into `Person.Rank`)

```
var groupedData = data.GroupBy(p => p.name).Select(g => new { name = g.Key, score = g.Sum(p => p.score)}).OrderByDescending(x => x.score);
var persons = groupedData.Select((p,i) => new Person(i+1, p.name, p.score));
```

Comment: Greetings, thank you for your reply. I tried your proposed solution, but I am still not getting the correct ranking :S

Comment: The rank's encoded in the list position, I'll update the answer to provide it in `Person.Rank`

Comment: Perfect! Now i need to figure out how to fix the ranking for the ones who will have the same score. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I'd group by score, order by score then create the rank by aggregating by the count of elements in each group

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question to this a while back. My problem was that if people have the same score it will assign the wrong rank to the person. With your current code if John also had a score of 7 he would be ranked #2 as you are ordering by score and just using its position in the list when hes really tied for #1.

Here was my question and solution: [Get the index of item in list based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202232/get-the-index-of-item-in-list-based-on-value)

Comment: Thank you fo ryour reply. Can you kindly please explain the solution as I didn't understand how its implementation resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

How about an extension method doing ranking:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectRank<TSource, TValue, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
     Func<TSource, TValue> valueSelector, 
     Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector)
            where TValue : struct
        {
            TValue? previousValue = default(TValue?);
            var count = 0;
            var rank = 0;
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                count++;
                var value = valueSelector(item);
                if (!value.Equals(previousValue))
                {
                    rank = count;
                    previousValue = value;
                }
                yield return selector(item, rank);
            }
        }
```

Usage `profiles.SelectRank(x => x.Score, (x, r) => new { x.Name, Rank = r })`. This method do only 1 iteration of the source. I do recommend to use a sorted `source` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Adding code here for completion as tournament example:

```
var entriesByPoints = tournament.Entries.GroupBy(g=>g.Picks.Sum(s=>s.TournamentContestant.TotalScoreTargetAllocatedPoints)).Select((group)=> new { 
            Points = group.Key,
            Entries = group.ToList()
            });

var entriesByRankWithPoints = entriesByPoints.OrderByDescending(ob=>ob.Points).Select((p,i) => new {
            Rank = 1 + (entriesByPoints.Where(w=>w.Points > p.Points).Sum(s=>s.Entries.Count())), 
            Points = p.Points, 
            Entries = p.Entries
        });
```

Results:

[image]