# Include Images as Observable Collection in C#

Tags: c#, image, list, linq, observablecollection

I just asked a question regarding linq for ranks in C#: [Linq List Ranking in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838787/linq-list-ranking-in-c-sharp/45838870?noredirect=1#comment78636006_45838870) which was answered. The question was to rank a list of people I have based on their score. So now I would like to add a number of stars that are equal to the person's score. For example:

```
 Rank Name Score Stars
  1   John  5    *****
  2   Ed    4    ****
  3   Sara  3    ***
```

The stars should be an actual .png star image. My question is, what would be the best way to implement this? Here's an attempt I tried, but it's not working with me:

```
   public class Person
    {

        public int Rank { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
        public Image Star { get; set; }

        public Person(int rank, string name, int score, Image star)
        {
            Rank = rank;
            Name = name;
            Score = score;
            Star = star;

        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);

        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        var data = lines.Select(line => {
        var column = line.Split(',');
        var name = column[0];
        int score = int.Parse(column[1]);
        int rank =0;
        Image star = new Image();

        return new { name, score, avg, rank, star };
    });

        var groupedData = data.GroupBy(p => p.name).Select((g, i) => new { name = g.Key, rank = i + 1, score = g.Sum(p => p.score), star = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"\Pics\MinusRate.png", UriKind.Relative))}).OrderByDescending(x => x.score);

        var persons = groupedData.Select((p, i) => new Person(i+1, p.name, p.score,p.star));

    foreach (var person in persons) {
        Persons.Add(person);
    }
    datagrid.ItemsSource = Persons;

    }
```

So what would be the best approach to include stars into this list?

Comment: To add to Waescher's answer: Is this XAML? If this is XAML, the stars should be defined in [Path Markup Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax), displayed with a [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

**In my opinion you should definitely put that as UI concern.** Don't try to prerender the star images for the memory representation of your data. You have the information there (`int Score`), that's it. Let the rest do your UI.

Imagine any developer requesting the data for non-UI purposes: He would certainly not expect the code to render images for each query and he might wonder where the memory consumtion (both, in RAM and network traffic) comes from.

Once the data hits the UI, you can do your imaging. For example, if you go for GDI+ for example, you could render the image like this:

```
// the icon file with one single star
var starIcon = Image.FromFile(...);

// the image of all stars (the width has to be the width of one star multiplied by the count of stars)
var image = new Bitmap(starsCount * starIcon.Width, starIcon.Height);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < starCount; i++)
    {
        // place the star icon to its position in the loop
        int x = (i * starIcon.Width);

        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dbsak4dc(v=vs.110).aspx
        g.DrawImage(starIcon, x, 0, starIcon.Width, starIcon.Height);
    }

    g.Flush();
}
```

Note this is more like pseudo-code out of the head - I did not throw it into a compiler, so it might not compile like that.

### Update:

I made a working fiddle over here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HPB7BR

Note that you won't need `GetImageFromURL()` it's just to get an image into that online fiddle. And, because I cannot show the image as output in that fiddle, I chose to show the image's size as output. Anyway, the image in variable `image` is ready to use. You can change the `starCount` to see how the width of the image changes accordingly.

Comment: Greetings Waescher, thank you for your reply i highly appreciate it. And thank you for your answer, it's pretty clear. But in the end this means that the stars will be in a separate list is that correct?

Comment: I mean you could use an empty `Person.Image` property which you populate in the UI afterwards to have it all in one place. Anyway, I'd go for a separate structure. This could be a `Dictionary<Person, Image>`, for example. Depending on the platform technology you're using for the front end ...

Comment: Greetings @Waescher I have beein trying to answer but it's not working with me. I decided to go with separate structure as you have mentioned but I am still unable to make it work. I am unable to get the images to appear based on the number of average :(

Comment: No problem. I made a working fiddle over here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HPB7BR. Note that you won't need `GetImageFromURL()` it's just to get an image into that fiddle. Because I cannot draw the image as output, I chose to show the image's size as output but the image in variable `image` is ready to use. You can change the `starCount` to see how the width of the image changes.